# Estoy tratando de convertir un objeto XML a un JSON y me devuelve este error en NetBeans

Tags: java, xml, netbeans, spring-boot, soap

Le paso un Numero de Cuil por parametro en un post a un servicio SOAP y cuando me convierte las fechas me devuelve este error en el postman:

**"Error: ; nested exception is: \n\torg.xml.sax.SAXException: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid date\njava.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid date"**

alguna solucion que me puedan dar?

los parametros de fecha estan declarados de esta manera

```
    private java.util.Date fechaCertificacionServicio; 
    private java.util.Date fechaFinRol;
```

Comment: qué es un número de Cuil? Por qué debería ser transparente convertir un número a Date? Cómo está enviándose esos parámetros Date? Puedes [edit] la pregunta y añadir el código relevante

Comment: Recuerda agregar el código donde realizas lo que comentas en tu pregunta, ¿Cuál es el formato de la fecha?. revisar [ask],saludos.

Comment: Hola dieguillo, podrías mostrarnos como instancias las fechas?, gracias!.